# What is the naming convention of JNI call in android

Tags: android

For example, in android Java code, it calls a native method:

```
private native final String native_getParameters();
```

Where/how should I grep where is the C++ method defined `native_getParameters();`?

Thank you.

Comment: somewhere here maybe? https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/jni

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ method will also contain your namespace (e.g. com.domain.your) and classname (e.g. YourActivity), it will look something like

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_domain_your_YourActivity_native_1getParameters(JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz)
```

Note the C++ _1 equates to the _ in your Java method